# Why can't I set my array to something in vb.net after it has been declared

Tags: .net, vb.net

Why can you do this in vb.net:

```
Dim numbers As Integer() = {1, 2, 3}
```

But not this:

```
Dim numbers As Integer() 
numbers = {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: Array literals in VB.net are only usable at creation time, probably due to the other language syntax features which would increase the parsing challenges of an already fairly chaotic language.

Comment: Uhhm, that compiles and works for me (.NET 4)